# large general american audio archive

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for a large (at least several hours) collection of audio records accompanied by transcriptions (just text, timing is not important) narrated by one person whose accent can roughly be described as General American, preferably male, high pitched would be ideal. Is collecting the audio books narrated by one person the only way to obtain such a treasure? What narrator would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.thecreativemuggle.com/best-audiobook-narrators/

Lists some audiobook readers.  [Julia Whelan](https://jmwhelan.com/narrator/) has narrated over 400 books A fairly standard GA accent. Female.

Or [Ray Porter](https://www.audible.co.uk/search?searchNarrator=Ray+Porter) Again, hundreds of books, more sci-fi, Fairly neutral GA accent. lower pitched than Julia but male.

Comment: Ray porter is a great narrator, but he does often change his accent for different characters. Non-fiction narration would probably be better than fiction.